Count the number of Choices in a SharePoint List Column using Power Automate
Afternoon,
I've got a sharepoint list and I'm trying to create a new column to count the number of individual items in a choice column, so it can be used a part of a formula. I.e for for test 1 in the table the count would be 4 & for test 2 it would be 1
Table with multiple choice column

I've found various posts with approaches using a power automate flow but none of them are quite right for what i've got.
If anyone has any ideas for how best to achieve this I'd really appreciate it.  I had thought i'd be able to do this with a formula but it seems more complicated and is starting to drive me a bit nuts now!
Various posts showing how to sum up the values which didn't quite work
Screen clip of the bit where i'm getting problems included below


Got an attempt we can critique?

I tried following this approach https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/711637/count-multiple-selected-items-in-sharepoin-online

I've added a screen clip to the main post of the bit where It seems to fall over as it won't let me add it to this comment
